# Adding remote in git that is not on GitHub or anyHub

Tags: git

Git noobie/intermediate here...

I have a client who says he did `git init` in a remote folder so I can make git changes.

Am I wrong that a repo must be hosted on GitHub or GitLab or some other place?

I see a `.git` the folder in there `(http://hisdomain/this/is/the/folder/.git)` but I don't know how to add the remote, i.e.

`git remote add origin http://hisdomain/this/is/the/folder/.git` doesn't work.

Typically I see something like `http://hisdomain/this/is/the/repo.git` for a remote repo, i.e. ending it dot git.

Am I missing the syntax because I can't seem to add the remote correct and get a `fatal: repository xyz not found`

Comment: The problem is you should read first the basics for git. https://try.github.io/ then i think you can solve your problem on your own. If you want to share the repo you have to clone it from the remote repository that is hosted on a server or a provider like Github.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: I understand the basics for sure and use git all the time, but I suppose I could have abbreviated my question to: can git work between any local and remote folders without any repo provide, GitLab/Hub,etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting software like github or gitlab is not required.

If you are able to see their git folder by browsing to, in your example, `http://hisdomain/this/is/the/folder/.git`, then the remote URL should be `http://hisdomain/this/is/the/folder`.  (That is, the URL does *not* go all the way into the `.git` metadata folder; and in fact it would be more typical for the central repo to be bare, so that it wouldn't have a `.git` folder at all.)  In this scenario, the web server is the only server software required (so long as things are configured correctly on their end).

Also you can use a relative path or `file://` URL if you have direct filesystem access to the repo (as in a shared drive).

And it is common to use `ssh` as the remote access mechanism as well.

Software like github is popular and can add a lot of useful features for team collaboration, but git does not require them and can be used in distributed fashion on its own.

Answer (score 0):

#### `git init`

> I have a client who says he did git init in a remote folder so I can make git changes.

`git init` will allow you to start track changes with git in the current folder. The outcome is :

- `.git`, a folder in the current directory
- `master` branch which is the default branch

[image]

#### `git remote`

> Am I wrong that a repo must be hosted on GitHub or GitLab or some other place?

Git can be attached (`git remote`) to any (single or multiple) servers(s) locally or on remote servers.

```
# Add remote to your git repository
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/dummy1.git

# Check to see a list of your remotes
git remote -v
```